# Can I get Simulink blocks from commlib individualy

Tags: simulation, matlab, library

We were simulating communication with DPCM modulator in school. I saved the Simulink scheme and now I would like to simulate some more situations at home, but my commlib doesn't have the modulator we were using. commsrccod2/DPCM Encoder and commsrccod2/DPCM Decoder

I tried to google those, but didn't find anything useful.

Can I download those blocks? Or can I somehow upgrade the Communication library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't download said library.

There is one thing you could do. Open the simulink file again on the original machine and then UNLINK the blocks of interest.

A lot of simulink modules are built out of lower level common simulink blocks.